Extract URL Root Domain From Subdomain (Google Spreadsheet)
i need to extract root domain from subdomain on google spreadsheet
Google Sheet Example
I want result as following:
ddd.example.com > example.com
www.ddd.example.com -> example.com
got root domain from subdomain list

You could try:
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A11;"(?:[^.]+\.){2}[^.]+$"))


I like REGEX but I am really poor in regex pattern. This should be accepted answer. ^ from me.

Try the following formula-
=TEXTJOIN(".";1;CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(A2;".");-3;-2;-1))

For dynamic spill formula try-
=MAP(TOCOL(A2:A;1);LAMBDA(x;TEXTJOIN(".";1;CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(x;".");-3;-2;-1))))


